# Cannot open the update manager or software centre in ubuntu 12.04

Tags: updates, software-center, update-manager

I get the following message:

```
An unresolvable problem occurred while initializing the package information.
Please report this bug against the 'update-manager' package and include the following error message:
'E:Type 'b-src' is not known on line 2 in source list /etc/apt/sources.list.d/cdemu-ppa-precise.list'
```

Comment: Run `sudo mv /etc/apt/sources.list.d/cdemu-ppa-precise.list /etc/apt/sources.list.d/cdemu-ppa-precise.list.bak` and then try to open update-manager or software center.

Comment: Let me put that as an answer, select that as the answer to your question so that the issue can be marked as solved..

Comment: check my answer..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is due to the malformed source list of the CDEmu PPA. Run the following command to rename the source list of teh PPA and then open software center or update manager:

```
sudo mv /etc/apt/sources.list.d/cdemu-ppa-precise.list /etc/apt/sources.list.d/cdemu-ppa-precise.list.bak
```

Also seems that [CDEmu has dropped the support](https://answers.launchpad.net/cdemu/+question/236176) for Ubuntu 12.04, so you can remove the source list of CDEmu if you want.